# glitchy behaviour div with background image, border radius in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm encountering some glitchy behaviour in chrome.

I'm trying to have a `div` with a `border-radius`, a `background-image`, a `border` and `overflow:hidden`.

Within that div is some kind of overlay that has to be 'masked' by the `overflow:hidden` and `border-radius` properties of the parent div.

This works but I'm seeing a fine border of the `background-image` between the overlay div and the `border` of the parent div.

Is there a workaround for this?

```css
body{
  background-color:black;
  }

.circle{
  background-image: url('http://www.augustaga.gov/images/pages/N1617/Black%20tupelo%20-%20photo%201.jpg');
  
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  overflow:hidden;
  
  
}
.overlay{
  top: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  height : 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:white;
  text-align: center;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="overlay"> text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `background-clip: padding-box;` to your .circle class

```
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box; 
-moz-background-clip:    padding; 
background-clip:         padding-box;
```

[Source](http://tumble.sneak.co.nz/post/928998513/fixing-the-background-bleed)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Pascal. Adding the lines you provided makes the glitchy border smaller but doesn't remove it completely. https://jsfiddle.net/bm8g55hw/2/

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

You need to remove the border :2px solid white;
form .circle class.

so it should be:

```
.circle{
  background-image: url('http://www.augustaga.gov/images/pages/N1617/Black%20tupelo%20-%20photo%201.jpg');
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* border: 2px solid white; */
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Removing the border doesn't help.